# css cursor:pointer

Tags: html, css, browser, mouse-cursor

I have this code over here

```css
.file-wrapper {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.file-wrapper input {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  filter: alpha(opacity=1);
  -moz-opacity: 0.01;
  opacity: 0.01;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.file-wrapper .button {
  background: #79130e;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding: 4px 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<span class="file-wrapper">
  <input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" />
  <span class="button">Choose a Photo</span>
</span>
```

in Safari and Google chrome browsers it does not show the cursor as pointer, so what's wrong?

Comment: While having a JSFiddle is a good thing, please always include some relevant code in here as well in case JSFiddle ceases working at some point. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, you're the one who's not helping us understand the problem. Expecting us to vote your question up when it's not our fault that we can't understand it is over the top.

Comment: @Mor Sela  u want cursor for this input file  just check this link
http://jsfiddle.net/mnjKX/7/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Styling a `<input type='file'>` can be hit-and-miss.

A lot of functionality is removed from these fields, due to security issues, including some CSS styling functionality. This is because if a file input field can be styled to look like something else, it may be possible for a malicious site to trick users into uploading files without intending to.

The exact features which are disabled for file input fields varies between browsers, so my guess is that the `cursor` style is disabled for these fields in Webkit-based browsers but not in other browsers.

I can see in your Fiddle that you've made quite an effort to get around some of these restrictions by overlaying a button on top of your file input field, but my guess is that the cursor restriction is going to be harder to work around.

If this is the case, then it is something you are just going to have to live with.